# How to remove "Optimized for iPhone 5" on AppStore

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I've just submitted an app. And my app does not update for iPhone 5. But app store was shown "Optimized for iPhone 5". 
How can remove this text?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a requirement now for all new submissions to be iPhone 5 ready. As soon, as you have the `Default-568h@2x.png` image in your bundle, your app is "iPhone 5 optimized".

// Update: As of Xcode 5 and AssetCatalogs, any app is "iPhone 5 optimized".

Answer (score 0):

You cant, Apple add that text to your app description automatically